# Transferring ownership of a specific Google Doc file using google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, google-docs, google-apps, google-api-ruby-client

I'm looking to transfer ownership of a specific Google Docs file using the Google Apps API. There are many accounts on a single Google Apps domain. There are many files I would like to transfer so I do not want to do it manually.

In the UI I've only seen the ability to transfer ownership of all files from a particular user rather than individual files.

I've looked through the GitHub page for the google-api-ruby-client gem, but I was unable to come up with a solution. Can someone point me in the right direction or post an example?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Google Drive API.  Specifically the Permissions "update" method.
First find/get the File ID, using the Files.List method, which will allow you to search using a query.  Then use the Permissions.Update (or Patch) method, making sure to set the transferOwnership parameter to True.

Full documentation is here: [Google Drive API - Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update)